# $C^*$ algebras whose nontrivial projections form a non empty compact connected set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Apart from $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. what is  an example of  a $C^*$ algebra $A$ whose set of non trivial  projections form a non empty compact connected set?
Is there an example of this  situation such that $A$  has trivial center?
Is there an example of this situation such that $A$ is a  simple  $C^*$ algebra?

Comment: Compact in what topology -- do you mean the norm topology inherited from A?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes I mean the norm topology.

Comment: I don't know much about functional analysis, but if I'm reading things right, then the trace on a type II factor is a surective map from the set of projections to $[0,\infty]$ which I think has connected fibers. If this map is continuous, that would tell us the set of projections in a type II factor is connected. I suspect that the set of projections is rarely compact in the norm topology though, especially if one is deleting the trivial projections from an apparently-connected set.